# Convert wav to mp3 with Lame.exe - ProgressBar?

Tags: c#, vb.net, mp3, wav

I'm doing some converting of wav-files to mp3 and I use lame.exe.
Now, when using "lame.exe sourcefile.wav endfile.mp3" in cmd it works great and shows it's own progressbar. But is it possible to have my own progressbar inside my application form to show it's progress? Because when using the command from my application, it just converts and doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that in order to get a progress bar, you should really be using lame as an API rather than as a straight executable. I suggest you try to find some class libraries wrapping lame.

Having done a quick search, [LameShell](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/LameShell.aspx) might do what you want. Ironically, that *does* wrap the executable instead of the library... I'm not sure how it manages to get progress, but it does expose an appropriate event.

Comment: Yea, `lame.exe` alone won't give you want you need.

Comment: Ah, thanx! I'll check this out! :) I knew it was possible somehow :)